# How to invert direction of brackets (for a right to left text) for arabic language

Tags: android, arabic, bidi

When I am trying to use brackets in Arabic language, they are getting reversed as shown in the attached [image: Screenshot].
I have tried using textDirection RTL and BidiFormatter, but none of them works.
The correct string is something like this "(باقة مسافر إسبوعي (مسبق".
Does anyone know, how to solve it?

Comment: wheres the screenshot??

Comment: Sorry i do not see that something is reversed. Please post a picture how you want it instead too.

Comment: @greenapps: I have edited my question for the correct string :)

Answer (score 4):

I have found it.
The solution is below:

```
String targetString = "\u200E"+originalString
```

Comment: @Melebius this worked perfectly for me. Took whole day to get here.
I had the same problem that the brackets/parentheses were misplaced in urdu/hindi/arabic localisation. After putting (\u200E) got the right string with properly placed parentheses.
P.S - I am trying to include all the keywords so that one might find it easily.

Comment: @MominKhan The credit should go to [hong chainan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4268248/hong-chainan). I’ve just edited a minor grammar problem here and don’t know much about the topic…

Comment: not working with flutter, is there any way for flutter?

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution its works

Copy this lines and paste it in strings.xml file in res\values

for English

```
    <string name="email_optional">Email (optional)</string>
```

For Arabic

```
    <string name="email_optional">&#41;اختياري&#40;إيميل </string>
```