# android EditText password in Arabic locale issue (in samsung devices only)

Tags: android, android-edittext, passwords, special-characters, samsung-mobile

I hava a password EditText in Arabic default locale.
when I write special characters like that

"!@#$%^&*()NA"

in password EditText and send it to server ,it reach like that

"!@#$%^&*)(NA"

this is happed just in password EditText in Arabic Locale in samsung devices only.. I tested this issue in sony, lg and huawei devices and this issue didn't exist

anyone can help me in this issue !?

Comment: maybe here is an explanation...: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405747/how-to-invert-direction-of-brackets-for-a-right-to-left-text-for-arabic-langua

Comment: ok, but any solution of this issue programmatically or force it to encode it in English encoding way